# How to call function dynamically in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've set of `html codes`, I want to have a function for each set where I can pull some data or do some activities, so basically I need to be calling function according to the html codes present in `DOM`, suppose I've header section I want to collect menu items and I've sliders where I want to collect slider information, So I need to call header function to do the activity accordingly and slider function to do the activity, I went across some info about `eval()` but I guess it has lot of demerits and is being obsolete. Please suggest me how can I achieve it.

HTML Code:
**Header**

```
<div class="header" data-nitsid="1">
    <div class="branding">
        <h1 class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo@2x.png" alt="" width="25" height="26">NitsOnline</a>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul class="header-top-nav">
            <li class="has-children">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**Slider**

```
<div id="slideshow" data-nitsid="2">
    <div class="revolution-slider">
        <ul>    <!-- SLIDE  -->
            <!-- Slide1 -->
            <li data-transition="zoomin" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="1500">
                <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x1200" alt="">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to collect data from both elements and pass the data to my views of laravel framework where it will generate a popup for each section for editing purpose.

```
$('.page-content-wrapper').find('[data-nitsid]').each(function() {
    // getting data to call function
    var nits = $(this).data("nitsid");

    // calling function
    design.nits();
}

var design = {};

design.1 = function() {
    // do ajax request to views of header
}

design.2 = function() {
    // do ajax request to views of slider
}
```

Comment: you can pass onclick to the html to get certain parameters and define that into js..not sure what does you want exactly

Comment: @akshaypadwal I don't want onclick method, I'm trying to build popups for respective section present in DOM

Comment: I think you mean `design[nits]();`, do you?

Comment: @NitishKumar. It is very unclear what you are asking. Can you give an example of data you want to process?

Comment: @eisbehr: yes I want it like same, but how can I call it, I mean whats is best way to execute this.

Comment: The `()` **is** the execution! Just try it this way ...

Comment: A function name or object property can't be just a number! Your code is invalid now and will not work! But still, `design[nits]();` is what you need!

Comment: @eisbehr: Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You canot use literal number as a property name. If you want to call property `1` of object `design` use `design[1]` instead. Also, you cannot assing property to non-initialized variable, you must use `var design = {};` to make it object. If your property of `design` object is stored in `nits` variable, then call it as `design[nits]();`. Also, next time don't forget to test your code before posting it here. You've forget `)` after your first function.

```
$('.page-content-wrapper').find('[data-nitsid]').each(function() {
    // getting data to call function
    var nits = $(this).data("nitsid");
    // calling function
    design[nits]();
});

var design = {};

design[1] = function() {
    // do ajax request to views of header
};

design[2] = function() {
    // do ajax request to views of slider
};
```

Comment: If using numerical index maybe better use an `array` instead of an `object` in your declaration of `design`. It would be more consistent ...

Comment: @eisbehr. I think it is better to use object, because only `design[1]` and `design[2]` have numeral indexes. As you can see from code, `nits` variable is always string, so I assume that OP want to add string indexes to `design` variable. Also, if you read edit history of the question, you wil find that `design[1]` was `design.header` and `design[2]` was `design.slider`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `design[nits]();`.
This will get the property `nits` of `design` and execute it with `()`.

But there is another problem. Your `design` will be declared after the `each` loop, so it is not available inside. You have to place it before.

```js
$(function() {
    var design = {};

    design.funcOne = function() {
        alert("funcOne called");
    }

    design.funcTwo = function() {
        alert("funcTwo called");
    }

    $('div[data-nitsid]').each(function() {
        var nits = $(this).data("nitsid");
        design[nits]();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-nitsid="funcOne">
  I will call 'funcOne'!
</div>
<div data-nitsid="funcTwo">
  I will call 'funcTwo'!
</div>
```